# Connect C# to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

i have code some small program. so i want to send data to MYSQL Database. This is the my code and this is in a dll file. so i need to call it in my GUI application. Here is the connection code (dll code)

```
class DBConnect
{
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    //Constructor
    public DBConnect()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    //Initialize values
    private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "connectcsharptomysql";
        uid = "username";
        password = "password";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + 
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
    //open connection to database
    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Close connection
    private bool CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

this is GUI Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using codeSnips;
using connectionManager;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        getAnswers obj1 = new getAnswers();
        DBConnect dbconnect = new DBConnect();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Warrning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime date1 = dtp1.Value.Date;
            DateTime date2 = dtp2.Value.Date;
            TimeSpan result = obj1.getdateDiffrance(date1, date2);
            txt1.Text = result.ToString(@"dd");


        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float dayfee = float.Parse(txt2.Text);
            int alldays = int.Parse(txt1.Text);
            float totfee = obj1.totalFeePayble(dayfee,alldays);
            txt3.Text = totfee.ToString();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           dbconnect.OpenConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

so how can i call the database open function

Comment: What issue are you having? I see a connection string in your first code example and you are calling "OpenConnection" when you click button5, so what's the problem?

Comment: i want to show message box if connection is ok or no

Comment: Are you just copy-pasting code from [CodeProject's Connect C# to MySQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL)? You should do a little more research, like reading the manual. See: [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual 25.2.3.3.5. State](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection-state)

Comment: I have edited my answer a couple times @user2751419, make sure you check the new stuff ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you are calling `DBConnect` from a different class you need to make it public:

```
public class DBConnect {...}
```

AND you would need to make the methods `OpenConnection` and `CloseConnection` public as well.

```
public bool OpenConnection() {...}
public bool CloseConnection() {...}
```

then you just need to check the return value of `dbconnect.OpenConnection()` if you just want a message box.

Something like this would work, though this should be pretty basic stuff...

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (dbconnect.OpenConnection())
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened Successfully!");
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed!");
       }
    }
```

Or you could get all fancy with a ternary to reduce the amount of code.

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       dbconnect.OpenConnection() ? 
           MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened Successfully") :
           MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed!");
    }
```

Here's why:

In your `DBConnect` Class, the function `OpenConnection` returns a value of type `bool`.  So when you call your method on your `dbconnect` object, it returns `true` if the connection opened, and `false` if there was an exception during the connection attempt.  So `dbconnect.OpenConnection()` either equals true or false depending on the results of that method's execution.  We check that value in `button5_Click(...)` and voila!

A couple tips:

1. Consider changing the way you declare your connection string.  The way you are doing it is hard to read, and completely unnecessary.  Most people either declare it all in one string, or in a config file (read up on Ado.Net).
2. Calling `Initialize()` in your constructor is also a bit odd, you could just assign those values inside the constructor itself.  And the name "Initialize" is not good practice, other people reading your code wont know what it does by looking at it.
3. If you are going to pop-up GUI related components (i.e. `MessageBox`) from your `Form`, you should consider removing the MessageBox's from your `OpenConnection()` method, or make the return value of `OpenConnection()` of type `int` so you can check the error code from your GUI and put as many MessageBox's there as you please.